# How would you describe the sound of flesh tearing?

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

How do you describe flesh-tearing?

Example

> "I reel the fishing pole back and hear *[word]* as a dead squirrel comes back on the end of the line."

Comment: It generally doesn't make much sound.

Comment: Here is an example- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UytcVmsGS_g

Comment: Depends on the nature of the flesh and what's tearing into it.

Comment: This is a little unclear...does the sound include coming out of the water, or only "tearing flesh"?  My first thought on reading the title is _squelch_.

Comment: are you looking for an onomatopoeia?

Comment: Yes I am looking for an onomatopoeia.

Comment: If you want to indicate something is answered, tick the check mark by the right answer. See the help centre: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers